# How do I refactor my Rails partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a partial with relatively deep conditionals and I was curious if this is appropriate for a partial?

I'm cycling through an array of Games and printing YES or NO based on whether or not the date of the game matches today's date.

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% x = 0 %>
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <% if game.date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] == today %>
     YES!
     <% i = 1 %>
  <% else %>
     <% unless i == 1 %>
     NO!
     <% i = 1 %>
     <% x = 1 %>
     <%= next_game %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would throw the whole lot into some kind of helper method:

**app/views/your_controller/your_view/_your_partial.html.erb**

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <%= played_today(game) %>
<% end %>
```

**app/helpers/your_helper.rb**

```
def played_today(game) # or whatever you want to call it
  # Use Date.current to be timezone aware, otherwise just Date.today
  game.date == Date.current ? 'YES' : 'NO'
end
```

I'm not sure what your `today` and `next_game` variables/methods do specifically, or if you really want to keep those `i`/`x` local variables for whatever reason, but if you do or they have some other extra meaning, please expand on your question.

As an aside, I'd recommend [keeping instance variables out of your partials](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503838/567863):

**app/views/your_controller/your_view.html.erb**

```
<% = render 'your_partial', games: @games %>
```

**app/views/your_controller/_your_partial.html.erb**

```
<% games.each do |game| %>
  <%= played_today(game) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this would work just fine for you, but I'm not sure why you have two variables or why you have `next_game`

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <% if game.date  == Date.today %>
    YES
  <% else %>
    NO!
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```