# Controller Resource Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone tell me what does Ryan mean by controller resource object in his first guideline in ([Rails: Should partials be aware of instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503838/rails-should-partials-be-aware-of-instance-variables/26651056#26651056))? Also can someone explain to me what does he mean in the first guideline that if instance variable is created to be shared across partials that only controller resource object will be shared? Thanks.